# Redirect users to location on google map with coordinates

Tags: google-maps, url

I've coordinates on a mobile web application. I'm trying to allow the user to click a button so the app will redirect the user to Google Maps with the coordinates.

Can I simply pass in the coordinates as a query string to the google maps url?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, like http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=51.917168,-0.227051

Answer (score 2):

You can pass parameters in URL with `?q=X,Y`

```
http://maps.google.com?q=48.8583736,2.2922926
```

Where 48.8583736 and 2.2922926 are the coordinates (of the [*Eiffel Tower*](http://maps.google.com?q=48.8583736,2.2922926)*!*).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters in URL with ?q=X,Y

https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir//51.917168,-0.227051/@51.917168,-0.2292397,17z